How to restrict access in Azure DevOps to only one specific board?
I have the boards "A", "B" and "C" in my Azure devops project.
I want to collaborate with an external consultant.
This person, we call him Peter, should only get access to the board "C".
The workitems that are displayed in the boards "A" and "B" should not be visible.

Do you have a recommendation how to solve this requirement?
Is there a possibility to grant permission only to the area of board "C"?

I defined a new area "Area C" for the board "C".
I defined a new team "External C".
I added Peter to the team "External C".
Peter was still able to see also the work items that are visible on the boards "A" and "B".

Under Boards, click on Areas.
Select Area C (which corresponds to Board "C").
Click on the Security button to configure permissions.
Ensure Peter (or the External C team) has Read access to this area.
Then, select Area A and Area B for Boards A and B.
Explicitly deny "View work items in this node" permission for Peter or the External C team for these areas. If you haven't created a new team create one- Go to "Project settings" -> Teams.
Create a team named "External C" if you haven't already done so.
Assign "Area C" as the default area path for this team.
Assign Peter to this team.

Under the External C team settings, ensure that the only area path selected is Area C.
This ensures that when Peter accesses the project, he is only shown items associated with Area C and verify Board Access

You can do like as below:

Go to "Project Settings" > "Teams" to create 3 teams in the project. For example, TeamA, TeamB and TeamC. If so, each team will have a board in this project. Add the external consultant as member of TeamC.


Go to "Project Settings" > "Project configuration" > "Areas" to create 3 area paths. For example, AreaPath_TeamA, AreaPath_TeamB and AreaPath_TeamC.


Go to "Project Settings" > "Team configuration" > select the team > "Areas" to add the area path to each team. After add the area path to each team, go back to "Project configuration" > "Areas", you can see each area path has its team assigned.


On "Project configuration" > "Areas", open the security hub of AreaPath_TeamA and AreaPath_TeamB, and set all the permissions to be 'Deny' for TeamC.



With above configurations, the members of TeamC will not has access to the work items assigned to TeamA and TeamB, and also cannot see work items on the boards of TeamA and TeamB.

Your description including the screenshots is great. Now the access control for the different boards works as expected. Thank you for the quick reply!
